# Is there a way to scrape the link of a video inside a webview in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, web-scraping, webview

I am working on a video scraping project using Flutter, what I want to implement now is to extract the video link from a website e.g. Youtube or Tiktok

I noticed Flutter has provided an awesome `webview_flutter` package for showing webpages, but it seems doesn't support to get the DOM tree of the page, or to inject/execute any javascript.

So my question is: `Is it possible and how can i scrape the video link from a webpage using Flutter?`

Or more generally, `Is there a way to get DOM html element?` or `Is there a way to get the html content?`

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use scrappy package.

Comment: @OMiShah do you mean https://pub.dev/packages/scrapy? it's cool but it's based on pure http request. What i want to achieve is to provide user a webview, then the app can get the content html from any webpage the user is browsing, and detect any video link from the content.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. But what you're trying to achieve is not possible. You have rely on 3rd party plugin or you have to use API or backed services.